# Webform + reCaptcha - still lot of SPAM

Tags: 6, webforms, security, advertising, captcha

Few months ago I installed reCaptcha module to use with webform. It worked perfectly: I can't submit form if I didn't provide correct captcha code. It worked even if I disable JavaScript. Problem is that I still get a lot of SPAM submissions from this webform. How this can be possible?
Drupal version: 6.27.
Webform version: 3.18.

Comment: Can you define "a lot of spam"? Are we talking 1000 a day or more like 10?

Comment: It's about 10 per day.

Comment: Probably real people entering spam. There is really no way to beat that.

Comment: Yeah, sounds like a meatnet.

Answer (score 4):

There is really no silver bullet that can be used to completely stop spam. Spam can only be minimized.

Spam entered by human beings will still always get through -- and there are more and more human being spam farms out there.

The best solution that I have found is to work with [Mollom](http://mollom.com/) rather than ReCaptcha.

Just as @Bisonbleu mentioned in the comment. Another module you can make use of is the [honeypot module](https://drupal.org/project/honeypot)

> Honeypot uses both the honeypot and timestamp methods of deterring
>   spam bots from completing forms on your Drupal site (read more here).
>   These methods are effective against many spam bots, and are not as
>   intrusive as CAPTCHAs or other methods which punish the user.

Comment: You use mollom + recaptcha? Doesn't that mean users could have to do 2 captchas to submit the form? - I have seen this on blogs and it's terrible for the user experience.

Comment: Changed that to using mollom

Comment: Have you read this post? Introducing the Honeypot form spam protection module (http://www.paulbooker.co.uk/drupal-development-services/article/introducing-honeypot-form-spam-protection-module)

Comment: Never knew of that module. Looks like a good one. Will definitely give it a try

Comment: In my experience you can't stop all spam. I have found little difference in effectiveness of mollum vs captcha vs honeypot, so I choose to use honeypot as it isn't horrible for users.

Comment: A mixed approach is a good idea. Mollom strict for human spammers, Honeypot for robots. And then, change them around once in a while in order to keep them guessing.

Comment: My experience is that Mollom is not reliable enough to use strict mode. It would block real people posting real content. Although in theory it should be getting better and eventually it should be ok.

Answer (score -1):

I recently changed to Confident CAPTCHA. It was a straight forward drupal implementation and my users like it.

Comment: Do you find it more effective and/or less intrusive than other options?